# Как отключить Use Gravity у объекта, с которым сталкивается player в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне надо, чтобы когда player сталкивался с каким либо объектом, с тегом Barier, у него этого объекта отключался  параметр Use Gravity в компоненте Rigidbody через C# скрипт, но я не знаю, как это можно реализовать.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: isKinematic вроде на это влияет

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html

`hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false`

, где `hit` - объект, с которым столкнулся игрок

Answer (score 0):

для 3д игры:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
      collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
}
```

для 2д игры:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)

{
    collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
}
```